# Is there a website where I can post my CV where potential academic employers can find me?

Tags: job-search, job

Is there a website where I can post my CV where potential academic employers can find me? To be more precise, I'm looking for postdoctoral position in the areas that uses differential geometry but could also use statistics, for example, computational neuroscience, computer vision, manifold learning etc.

P.S. this is my main question. But if you could answer the same question for industries for using the above topics and could access my CV online, that'd be well appreciated, because in case I don't get a postdoc, I'm keeping myself open to industry too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you heard about [Stackoverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)? (Industry)

Comment: Note that while the question/answer in the linked/duplicate question above refers to faculty positions, the situation is identical for postdocs -- namely that the supply of candidates so outnumbers the number of available positions that there's no need for a centralized CV clearinghouse.

Comment: @scaaahu: I haven't so far, but I just requested an invitation.

Answer (score 5):

Academic employers in my experience don't go looking on websites for candidates. We post jobs to our own websites, advertise in professional society magazines, and on certain mailing lists and LinkedIn. We get so many applicants this way, that actually searching out candidates on our own is frequently unnecessary.

Comment: _actually searching out candidates on our own is frequently unnecessary_ — I was with you until the last sentence.  Despite the large numbers of applications, it is sometimes necessary for recruiting committees to seek out candidates directly, if only to convince them to apply.  But then we're MUCH more likely to trawl directly through personal university web pages than some common site like LinkedIn.

Comment: @JeffE "Frequently uncessary" leaves some room for the infrequent case where it is necessary. Can you say how many times your department has had to do such trawling out of what number of recent hires?

Comment: _Can you say how many times your department has had to do such trawling out of what number of recent hires?_ — Much more often for tenured faculty than for assistant professors.  Almost everyone we've hired with tenure over the last decade applied only because someone contacted them and encouraged them to apply. That's probably true of about 20% of our recent assistant professors as well.

Comment: @JeffE, interesting and not too surprising. Has it ever been done for a  postdoc?

Comment: In my experience, that's the **only** way to hire a postdoc.  (My experience is limited to theoretical computer science.)